# node.js driver for mysql works in console but not in actual code

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have .js file with following code:

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
host: 'localhost',
user: 'root',
password: 'password',
database: 'databasename'});

function select(id,tablename){
connection.connect();
connection.query('select ' +tablename+'.property from databasename.'+tablename+' where id = '+id, function(err,result){
var string=JSON.stringify(result[0].property);
// alert(string); or console.log(string); 
});
connection.end();
}

// function go(){select(3,"tablename");} or select(3,"tablename");
```

where function.go() is called from button.onClick().
 And when I run it from console via "node filename.js" it works fine and shows correct data, but it doesn't work from button.onClick().

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think you mix up things here. A DB request is done from server-side code, not from client side. You can trigger a DB request on the server with an Ajax request, for example. Maybe you should get the basics right before going on.

Comment: https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql

Comment: Are you sure your `button.onClick()` event is firing ? And what are you using on frontend ? a library or vanilla js ?

Comment: I used alert to verify the button click and it worked. And it seems like it could not pass connecting.connect() line. I'm just using sublime text without any libraries and without vanilla js. I'm a beginner.

Comment: You should read and understand what @Robert is saying: you are trying to use a database connection module that is meant to be running on the server _in a browser_. That's not going to work. The programming language may be the same (JS), but that doesn't mean you can run inherently server-side code in a browser.

Comment: Oh, I see it now. Thanks for responding.

Answer (score 0):

your code is wrong.

You have written

```
var mysql = require(‘mysql'); var connection = mysql.createConnection({host: ‘localhost';user: 'root',password: 'password',database: ‘databasename'});function select(id,tablename){connection.connect();connection.query('select ' +tablename+'.property from databasename.'+tablename+' where id = '+id, function(err,result) {var string=JSON.stringify(result[0].property);/* alert(string); or console.log(string); */});
```

It should be

```
var mysql = require('mysql'); var connection = mysql.createConnection({host: 'localhost';user: 'root',password: 'password',database: 'databasename'});function select(id,tablename){connection.connect();connection.query('select ' +tablename+'.property from databasename.'+tablename+' where id = '+id, function(err,result) {var string=JSON.stringify(result[0].property);/* alert(string); or console.log(string); */});
```

At many places, you have started strings with `‘` and ended with `'` which might be causing the problem.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. But I think it is just my luck of writing post here cause the code works fine from console.

Comment: have you tried calling any other function ( even a simple console.log ) to verify that the button click is getting triggered ?

Comment: I used alert to verify the button click and it worked. And it seems like it could not pass connecting.connect() line.

Answer (score 0):

You should use single quote or double quote to enclose string.you have used `  instead of `'` 
Also remove semicolon after host:'localhost'. there should be a comma instead of semicolon

your code should be like this

```
 var connection = mysql.createConnection({host:'localhost',user:'root',password:'password',database: 'databasename'});


function select(id,tablename){

  connection.connect();
  connection.query('select ' +tablename+'.property from databasename.'+tablename+' where id = '+id, function(err,result) {
    var string=JSON.stringify(result[0].property);/* alert(string); or console.log(string); */

  });
}
```

Comment: I think it is just my luck of writing post here cause the code works fine from console.

Answer (score 0):

i think you mix sync and async. you need your callback for the query

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: 'password',
    database: 'databasename'
});

function select(id, tablename, callback){
    connection.connect();
    connection.query(`SELECT ${tablename}.property from databasename.${tablename} where id = ?`, [id], callback);
    connection.end();
}

function go () {
    select(3, "tablename", function (err, result) {
        // mysql response
    });
}
```

Comment: I tried it and it seems like it could not pass connection.connect() line in the first place.

Comment: the connection is working on me. may i know how you bind the event to the DOM ?